# My text-based game displays one frame behind

Tags: c++, ncurses

I'm working on the classic snake game where the snake goes around the screen eating stuff and getting longer in C++. I saw an example of it being made on Youtube, but decided I wanted to make it a bit more object oriented, plus I'm using ncurses (in Linux) to make it a bit more refined.

I've been programming a bit at a time and at this point, don't yet have the food set up. It's just a snake that starts moving when the arrow key is pressed and crashes once it hits a wall. What's keeping me from continuing is that the game seems to display a frame behind where the snake actually is. When it's moving and I press an arrow key to change direction, it moves one more time in the same direction before turning. (I have the frame rate turned down to one frame per second to make this obvious.) Also, if I let it just go straight into a wall, it moves to the second position from the wall and then triggers a game over and quits. However, if I push a perpendicular direction while it's at that second position, it'll move up against the wall and then start moving alongside it. The q (quit) button doesn't have such hesitation and causes the game to quit once the usleep function is finished. It would seem like the input and logic functions are working as expected, but the draw function is somehow lagging even though it's just after the other two.

Here's the code, and I'll put the command I use at the top in case anyone with Linux or a similar environment would like to try it themselves. I've made it so that it prints the coordinates of the snake at the bottom of the screen, but they match the drawn location of the snake. (For instance, if going to the left, you can see x gets to 2 and then the game ends, even though it's clearly programmed to kill the snake once it reaches 0, and you can make it move along column 1 by turning it.) I've been trying to figure this out for two days, even with gdb, and I keep finding other things I want to change, but can't seem to figure this one out. Please save me from this madness.

`g++ -g snakes.cpp -lncurses -o snakes`

```
// draw is one frame behind

#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

#define WIDTH 30
#define HEIGHT 30
#define MS_PER_FRAME 750
#define START_LENGTH 1

using namespace std;

bool gameOver;
enum eDirection { STOP, LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN };

class Snake
{
public:
    Snake(int i, int j);
    bool isHead(int i, int j);
    bool isTail(int i, int j);
    void moveSnake();
    bool collisionOccurred();
    void drawSnake();
    void setDirection(eDirection newDir);
    
private:
    short int x, y, length;
    short int tailx[20], taily[20];
    eDirection dir;
} snake (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2);

Snake::Snake(int i, int j)
{
    x = i;
    y = j;
    length = START_LENGTH;
    dir = STOP;
}

bool Snake::isHead(int i, int j)
{
    if (i == x && j == y)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool Snake::isTail(int i, int j)
{
    for (short int r = 0; r < length; r++)
        if (i == tailx[r] && j == taily[r])
            return true;
    return false;
}

void Snake::moveSnake()
{
    for (short int r = length; r >= 1; r--)
    {
        tailx[r] = tailx[r-1];
        taily[r] = taily[r-1];
    }
    tailx[0] = x;
    taily[0] = y;
    switch (dir)
    {
        case LEFT:
            x--;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            x++;
            break;
        case UP:
            y--;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            y++;
            break;
    }
}

bool Snake::collisionOccurred()
{
    if (x == 0 || x == WIDTH+1)
        return true;
    if (y == 0 || y == HEIGHT+1)
        return true;
    for (int l = 0; l < length; l++)
        if (dir != STOP && (x == tailx[l] && y == taily[l]))
            return true;
    return false;
}

void Snake::drawSnake()
{
    mvaddch(y, x, 'O' | COLOR_PAIR(2));
    for (int l = 0; l < length; l++)
        mvaddch(taily[l], tailx[l], 'o' | COLOR_PAIR(2));
    mvprintw(HEIGHT+2, 0, "Snake: %d, %d\n", x, y);
}

void Snake::setDirection(eDirection newDir)
{
    dir = newDir;
}

void drawBorder()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= WIDTH+1; i++)
        mvaddch(0, i, '#' | COLOR_PAIR(1));
    for (int i = 0; i <= WIDTH+1; i++)
        mvaddch(HEIGHT+1, i, '#' | COLOR_PAIR(1));
    for (int i = 0; i <= WIDTH+1; i++)
        mvaddch(i, 0, '#' | COLOR_PAIR(1));
    for (int i = 0; i <= WIDTH+1; i++)
        mvaddch(i, WIDTH+1, '#' | COLOR_PAIR(1));
}

void init()
{
    gameOver = false;
    initscr();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
    curs_set(0);
    start_color();
    init_pair(1, COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_BLUE); // border
    init_pair(2, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLACK); // snake
    init_pair(3, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK); // fruit
    drawBorder();
}

void deinit()
{
    endwin();
}

void draw()
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= HEIGHT; j++)
    {
        move(j, 0);
        for (int i = 1; i <= WIDTH; i++)
        {
            mvaddch(j, i, ' ');
        }
    }
    snake.drawSnake();
    refresh;
}

void input()
{
    switch (getch())
    {
        case KEY_UP:
            snake.setDirection(UP);
            break;
        case KEY_DOWN:
            snake.setDirection(DOWN);
            break;
        case KEY_LEFT:
            snake.setDirection(LEFT);
            break;
        case KEY_RIGHT:
            snake.setDirection(RIGHT);
            break;
        case 'q':
            gameOver = true;
            break;
    }
}

void logic()
{
    if (!gameOver)
        snake.moveSnake();
    if (snake.collisionOccurred())
        gameOver = true;
}

int main()
{
    init();
    draw();
    while (!gameOver)
    {
        usleep(MS_PER_FRAME * 1000);
        input();
        logic();
        draw();
    }
    deinit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try parsing it down to a minimum reproducible example and you'll probably find your answer. If not we'll be here.

Comment: `getch` when used with the arrow keys might return two keycodes.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an issue with getch. I changed it so getch puts its return into an int, then calls the switch statement based on that int. Between, it prints below the snake's coordinates the key pressed. It remains -11 (I assume ERR) except when I press a key. The arrows are 258 to 261 which only show up on one frame, but still they show up two frames after I press it. It's the usual -11 on the very next frame, then followed by the appropriate code. This backs up my thought that the screen gets drawn before the input is read, even though that's not how it's coded.

Comment: `getch` does a refresh.  If you were using the original version of snake, that would be different since BSD curses didn't do the refresh in getch.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, I finally figured this one out and I'm surprised the compiler didn't catch it. The response about getch doing a refresh led me in the right direction, though that wasn't a problem in itself.

Plain and simple, I forgot the parentheses after refresh in the draw routine, so it didn't refresh at that point. I didn't know getch does a refresh though it doesn't really matter since it'll be done again after the snake's position is recalculated a few milliseconds later, if that. However, leaving off the parentheses means it wasn't refreshing then, only by getch before the snake was moved, explaining why it seemed a frame behind.

Now I can only wonder why the compiler didn't fault out for that and what refresh does, if anything, without parentheses.